# How to detect hidden text from a pdf file using php

Tags: php, pdf

How can i detect hidden text from a pdf file using php. I know that there are different ways on how to hide a text from a pdf file. So I need to know if there is a way to check a pdf file if it has a hidden text in it using php.

I am still not familiar with the php libraries for pdf so I need to know which one does the job for this.

Comment: try tcpdf
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_054.phps

Comment: @SandipPingle Sorry, but the sample that you've sent creates a pdf file. I have a sample pdf file and I need to detect if it has a hidden text inside.

Comment: What sort of "hidden text" are you looking for? Small text? Text in the background color? Text in a font where each character looks like a space? Text covered by other graphic elements? .. Lots of more possibilities, so let's switch to another angle: text hidden in the *binary* file? Encrypted text? Steganographically encoded in lossless images?